# Which of the following is true?[Using Formal approach]

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, entire-functions, rouches-theorem

Let $f:\mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ be an entire function such that $$\lim _{z\to 0}\left|f\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)\right|=\infty. $$ Then which of the following is true?

1. $f$ is constant
2. $f$ can have infinitely many zeros
3. $f$ can have at most finitely many zeros
4. $f$ is necessarily nowhere vanishing

My Try:- Let $f(z)=z$, I could eliminate 1,2,4. So, Answer is 3. How do I solve formally?
$$\lim _{z\to 0}\left|f\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)\right|=\infty.\iff  $$
 for $\epsilon>0, \exists \delta: |z|<\delta \implies |f(1/z)|>\epsilon.\iff $  Put $w=1/z.$ for $\epsilon>0, \exists \delta: |1/w|<\delta \implies |f(w)|>\epsilon \iff $ for $\epsilon>0, \exists \delta: |w|>1/ (\delta) \implies |f(w)|>\epsilon$. So, the function has no zero out side the closed disk of radius $\delta$. So, Zeroes may or may not be lie inside the disk of radius $\delta$. How do I proceed further?

Comment: Possibly [related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/139472/entire-function-with-only-finitely-many-zeros) question.

Answer (score 1):

If the zeros lie in a bounded set and there are infinitely many of them, does that imply the zero set has a limit point?
If it does, what does that imply?

Comment: You mean, suppose it has infinitely many zeroes inside that disk. Then set of zeroes has a limit point in the closed disk. By Identity theorem, the function must vanish identically inside the disk. Right?

Comment: You've got it .

Comment: What happens entire function vanishes inside a closed disk?

Comment: If a function vanishes inside any closed disk (which is what you can conclude from the above), then it is identically 0.
Even more, if an entire function vanishes inside a single closed disk, it's identically zero since its zeros have a limit point.